# Unlink cache warning in CakePHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, caching, cakephp, filesystems

Every couple of weeks, a site I run encounters warnings that look like this:

> **Warning:** unlink(/var/www/html/app/tmp/cache/models/myapp_cake_model_default_sitename_modelname): No such file or directory in **/var/www/html/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php** on line **254**

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to the controller or method that's running when it occurs (in fact, I'm not sure I've seen a controller/method pair repeated in maybe a dozen instances of this type of warning), and there's no reason to believe that the warning come from unusual use cases (like being probed by bots).

The site is built on CakePHP version 2.2.3 and is running on AWS. I don't think the warnings are critical, but it'd be nice not to have them happen at all. Any thoughts on what's going on?

Comment: You'd have to look at where the `unlink` is called from. If a conditional perhaps 2 users trigger the event at the same time. The first `unlink` would delete it and the second would cause this error (because `No such file or directory`).

Comment: A race condition is indeed very possible, given how [**`FileEngine::clear()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.3/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php#L221) works, wich is why in later versions [**the unlink call is being error suppressed**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/1617).

Comment: A race condition would certainly help explain how infrequent the error is. Given that the code has been updated in later versions, is there anything terribly inadvisable about placing the @ before the unlink on the indicated line 254?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be certain without knowing the internals of your system. But my guess is that CakePhp cache engine is unable to write files to directory for some reason.

Here's my recommendation:

1. Check that the directory `/var/www/html/app/tmp/cache` exists, if not then create it.
2. Add write permission to the cache directory.

My suspicion is that the CakePhp Cache Engine is attempting to garbage collect files that failed to write.

Comment: Cache directory is definitely there with the appropriate permissions. To give you some idea of the frequency, we get ~3000 pageviews a day, but only see this error once every couple of weeks even though the methods from which the warning is generated are very common user actions.